# Combining windowing (groupBy) and mapGroupsWithState (groupByKey) in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Currently using Spark 2.2.0 structured streaming.

Given a stream of timestamped data with watermarking, is there a way to combine (1) the `groupBy` operation to achieve windowing by the timestamp field and other grouping criteria with (2) the `groupByKey` operation in order to apply `mapGroupsWithState` to the groups for custom sessionization?

Or is it that I have to settle with somehow embedding the windowing and other grouping logic into `groupByKey`?

For context:

- calling `groupBy`, which supports windowing, on a Dataset returns a [RelationalGroupedDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) which does not have `mapGroupsWithState`.
- calling `groupByKey`, which supports `mapGroupsWithState`, returns a [KeyValueGroupedDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset), but that has no support for windowing!

**Edit**:

The issue is now tracked by [SPARK-21641](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21641) -
*Combining windowing (groupBy) and mapGroupsWithState (groupByKey) in Spark Structured Streaming*.

Comment: Is there any update on the feature request, or did you figure out a workaround in the end?